# Establish the full value of a char * in string

Tags: c++

I want to know how to set the char pointer value "d" in "Stren"

```
char *d;
std::string Stren = *d;
```

Comment: no `std::string` in C; tag removed

Comment: but it is c ++, I have not defined the namespace, if I put std::string Stren = d; only sets the last value of char

Comment: @user4515480 what pmg was referring to is that the `c` tag is surely wrong on this question, since there's no `std::string` in the C language. The `std::string` class only exists in C++, not in C. Hence, you must not tag this question with `c`, only with `c++`.

Comment: Does `d` refer to a C-stye null-terminated string? These questions are usually implicitly answered by providing a fully-reproducing [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), described in arguably the least-read documents on this site, the [FAQ list](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for a single character requires a fill count.

```
std::string Stern( 1, *d );   // Stores a single character pointed by d.
```

For example:

```
char *d = "this is an example";
std::string Stern( 1, *d );  // Stern is now "t";
std::string Stern2( d );     // Stern is now "this is an example";

std::cout << d << std::endl;   // Outputs "this is an example" followed by '\n'
std::cout << *d << std::endl;  // Outputs "t" followed by '\n';
```

Comment: but for some reason only stores the last value taken "d"

Comment: Did you want the string pointed by d or the character pointed at *d?

Comment: Yes, for example, if I use: std :: cout << * d; displays everything but I want to store it all in string.

Comment: @user4515480 no, `std :: cout << *d;` doesn't "display everything", unless "everything" is a single char. If you used `std::out << d;` where `d` pointed to a C-style terminated string, *then* it would "display everything".